# C# pass array to Interop assembly

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, interop, unmanaged

I have created a .NET Interop assembly in LabVIEW which performs a mathematical function on an Input array and writes the result to two output arrays. The signature is:

```
void CFit(Array Input__32Array, out Array Output__32Array, out Array Result__32Array)
```

In C# the Input__32Array is actually an array of structure, the other two output arrays are 2-dimensional arrays. If I use this

```
double[,] OutputArray = new double[1650, 2]; // Output1
double[,] ResultArray = new double[20, 6]; // Output2
IData[] iData; //Input array

CFit( iData ,out ResultArray, out OutputArray);
```

the compiler throws an error - *Error CS1503    Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Reflex_UI.iData[]' to 'Reflex.CFit.Input__32Array__32[*]'*

**IData** structure is defined as the following in C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
public class IData
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
    public float L;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int D;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
    public float S;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short I;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
    public short C;
}
```

Question: How to pass the Input array (array of structure) to this Interop assembly?

This is my first post. I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: As per the definition of CFit, it requires Array type parameters. you need to cast the Idata input to Array type. More info on Array class can be found on MSDN

Comment: Please post all of the relevant interface code that was generated by LabView for the assembly in question.

Comment: Have you tried to use a struct instead of a class? The StructLayoutAttribute is not very useful on a reference type.

Comment: LabVIEW generates only the signature - void CFit(Array Input__32Array, out Array Output__32Array, out Array Result__32Array)

Comment: And what abou IData? Have you tried to make it a struct?

Comment: I can covert IData to a structure. How do I pass it ?

Comment: You just declare it as a struct instead of a class and pass it as before. There is nothing to convert. At least not in the code you habe provided.

Comment: Tried that the compiler throws the same error - cannot convert from IData[] to CFit.Input__32Array__32[*]